# Abstract classes and generics

Tags: java, oop, generics

Suppose I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
   ...
}

public class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
   ...
}
```

a builder:

```
public class Builder{
    static public ConcreteClass build(){
        ...
    }
}
```

and a generic function in some other class:

```
public <T extends AbstractClass> T myFunction(){
    T a = Builder.build();
    return a;
}
```

It was my understanding that the compiler should have enough information to allow such assignment, however, it throws an error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from ConcreteClass to T

Why is that and what are the potential dangers of such assignment?

Comment: Why are you trying to make it generic on T, when you just want to return `AbstractClass`?

Comment: As you are trying to use a builder pattern with inheritance maybe [this post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21210870/in-java-can-you-use-the-builder-pattern-with-required-and-reassignable-fields/21211472#21211472) might help, although it was a bit misplaced in that post as I understood the question fully after having posted this.

Comment: Maybe example is a little bit too simplified, I just wanted to show example of assignment part, everything else is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone could write this:

```
public class OtherConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
    ...
}

...

SomeOtherClass soc = SomeOtherClass.<OtherConcreteClass>myFunction();
```

In that call to myFunction, T is OtherConcreteClass, and you can't cast ConcreteClass to OtherConcreteClass.

Answer (score 0):

In short: T doesn't have to be ConcreteClass, it could also any sibling of ConcreteClass (e.g. if you declared ConcreteClass2 that also extended ConcreteClass).